# Using Serilog contextual without dependency

Tags: c#, serilog, structured-logging

I think the title could be a bit vague, but I couldn't come up with a better title.

My use case is this: I have a Web API project, which is using some "library" projects, taking care of business logic, and I want to use `Serilog` and its `LogContext` to put some properties so that I can track actions.

The issue that I have is that in my entry-point (Web API project), I don't have those properties to be able to do something like this:

```cs
using (LogContext.PushProperty("MyProperty", "my-value"))
{
  DoStuff();
}
```

It's inside my "library" projects that I have the values for those properties, but I feel that my business logic shouldn't necessarily depend on `Serilog.Context` to be able to add the property.

What I'm trying to say is that dependency on `Serilog` should ideally be in my entry-point project, and my business logic should depend on an interface of some kind.

[from here](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/), I know that `ILogEventEnricher` exists, but firstly it would imply the dependency on `Serilog` in my business logic. Furthermore, it would need to know about the property it's trying to set, but given that I need to add it in the beginning and in my entry-point project like this:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.With(new MyLogEnricher(/* I need to pass the "not-yet-known" object here*/);
```

which means I'm back to my original problem.

So, it seems that I'm facing a dilemma here that I don't know how to solve. Maybe my thought process is moving in the wrong direction, but anyway, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: why not create your own context that your log event enricher reads?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Can you give an example of some business logic that has internal context you want to log? Also, do your libraries contain data access implementations or are they purely domain/business code?

Comment: Wrong language but in https://github.com/jet/equinox I make the libs always take an ILogger and then layer on the values with the `.ForContext()` overloads on it - i.e. not depending on LogContext in the lib. Then a given transient or singleton object can pass in a logger (or `Log.Logger`).